# Correct query no longer working in SPROC

Tags: sql, sql-server

While testing an application that uses a stored procedure, I came upon an error that had actually been fixed some time before. When debugging the stored procedure, I found that the query which breaks is the following:

```
SET @LastSold = (SELECT last_sold_date
                   FROM   movement.dbo.dv_store_items
                   WHERE  Cast(store_number AS INT) = @Store
                          AND vendor_number = @Vendor
                          AND upc = @UPC
                          AND store_number <> 'CMPNY');
```

The error I receive for this is:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CMPNY' to data type int
```

The odd thing about this query is that when I run the same query outside of the stored procedure with the same criteria, it works perfectly fine. Even stranger is that this stored procedure was working just fine until I created an index on the table movement.dbo.dv_store_items:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX1] ON [dbo].[dv_store_items]
(
[upc] ASC,
[vendor_number] ASC,
[store_number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm honestly at a loss for words as to how this makes any sense, so any help would be *very* much appreciated

Comment: Try looking at the execution plan with and without (disable) the new non-clustered index. I'd think that the two plans will differ and because of this the order of operations in your WHERE changes in the two versions

Comment: `Cast(store_number AS INT)= @Vendor` and `store_number <> 'CMPNY'` in the same statement, and you wonder why you are getting an error like that? Suppose a row has CMPNY as store_number, what do you think the result of `Cast(store_number AS INT)` is?

Comment: @TT. I'm very much open to a different way of writing the query.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Ah, I see it now. I actually had to delete the original index and added it again sometime later. I had forgotten to add ([store_number])
INCLUDE to the index. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: There's a reasonable chance you will run into this problem again if you are mixing actual numbers and text in one column, and using `CAST(... AS INT)`. Casting text as an integer will result in an error. I'm assuming by using a particular index, it never encouters text and just numbers so the CAST would not fail.

Comment: Also, if `Cast(store_number AS INT) = @Store` holds (meaning it evaluates as true), the condition `store_number <> 'CMPNY'` will evaluate to TRUE. If store_number would differ from @Store you don't want to select the row anyway, so comparing the 'CMPY' is irrelevant. So the `store_number <> 'CMPNY'` check is irrelevant.

Comment: @TT. Ah, good eye! Thank you very much sir. In the answer I provided, I added the improvement you mentioned.

Comment: Answered alternative way of writing, with guarantee not to run into conversion problems. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fool-proof way to ensure you don't run into conversion problems (alpha to integer, like 'CMPY') is by using [TRY_CAST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx). This will return `NULL` if the cast cannot be made (ie, from 'CMPY' to INT). Available in SQL Server 2012+.

---

```
SET @LastSold = (
       SELECT 
           last_sold_date
       FROM
           movement.dbo.dv_store_items
       WHERE
           TRY_CAST(store_number AS INT)=@Store -- ensure you only select from actual integers
           AND vendor_number = @Vendor
           AND upc = @UPC
);
```

Comment: There are ways to do this in versions before SQL Server 2012, if a little more elaborate.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer because this solution seems to be the most robust. When compared to the solutions I presented above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the index I listed:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX1] ON [dbo].[dv_store_items]
(
[upc] ASC,
[vendor_number] ASC,
[store_number] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Should have been:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX1] ON [dbo].[dv_store_items]
(
    [store_number] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [upc],
    [last_sold_date],
    [vendor_number]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

The reason being, as Allan S. Hansen stated, "order of operations in your WHERE changes in the two versions".

Also, TT. raised a good point in the comments. This query could be further improved by filtering out the 'CMPNY' value altogether, making that part of my WHERE clause irrelevant:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX1] ON [dbo].[dv_store_items]
(
    [store_number] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [upc],
    [last_sold_date],
    [vendor_number])
WHERE store_number <> 'CMPNY'
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is still error-prone because query optimizer future behavior is unpredictable.
Check data before conversion. Quick demo

```
declare @store_number varchar(100) = 'CMPNY';
declare @store int = 1;

SELECT 1 WHERE CASE @store_number WHEN 'CMPNY' THEN -@store ELSE cast( @store_number AS INT) END = @store;
-- no result, no error

set @store_number = cast(@store  as varchar(100));

SELECT 1 WHERE CASE @store_number WHEN 'CMPNY' THEN -@store ELSE cast( @store_number AS INT) END = @store;
-- 1 row
```